# How to Transfer files(small) to mobile device over bluetooth 16.04

Tags: java, bluetooth, phone, transfer

ok, I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and I have a `java` phone. Now my question is how can I transfer files to my phone over `bluetooth` connection?

I searched, but all of the articles were about transferring to `android`.

Is there any software to do that?

**TIA**

### EDIT

Sorry for mistake. It is actually `transfer files from my phone to ubuntu over` bluetooth `connection`

Comment: What is a "java phone" ?

Comment: @PatrickNegus model: Symphony B12 - Local Company in BD

Comment: @SorenA java phone is those popular phones before android with java operating system if i answer simply. For more [details] (http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/javaenabled-mobile-phones-12347.html)

Comment: I doubt you can transfer files over Bluetooth from your phone unless the capability is located within the OS on the phone. This isn't a Ubuntu issue, but an issue with your phone.

Comment: @PatrickNegus :( that is sad. btw thanks for the info